# How can I show the keypad (type vktNumberPad) with decimal for input, with Delphi in android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

As would

```
edit.setInputType (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED)
```

In Delphi XE5.

I only see how to select the keyboard type `vktNumberPad`, but does not show the decimal.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The FMX Mobile samples (see Samples from the XE5 start menu, then FireMonkeyMobile) has a keyboardTypes demo that clearly shows how to use the `vktNumberPad` for the Zip Code entry, and it shows (and allows use of) the decimal.

Comment: "and it shows (and allows use of) the decimal"  How?. This example had already tried, but never shows the decimal. I tested on LG Optimus G and a Sansumg Galaxy S2

Comment: I opened the sample, set the target to my device (in this case a Nexus 7 II, Jelly Bean), and ran the application. When it started, I tapped the Zip Code edit area, and the keyboard appeared with numbers, +/-, and a decimal point. I tested by typing 123.45 (just to make sure the decimal could actually be used - it can).

Comment: Thanks, Ken, to me is still missing the decimal point, I guess depends on the device.

Comment: It may also depend on which keyboard software is installed. On my HTC device I can switch between the HTC keyboard, and ones I've downloaded (Google Keyboard, Swype and Hacker's Keyboard). I guess the stock Android keyboard is different again.
I wouldn't be surprised if different keyboards had different capabilities with regard to available keyboard layouts.
I'll experiment later....

Comment: Yeah, they all managed it

Comment: It's verry bugged. When you have more edit fields with different keyboardtypes it can also load the wrong keyboard! Most of the time it loads the keyboard of the previous edit field not from the current one.