# Is there a way of restricting characters and specifying a keyboard type with Delphi's InputQuery / InputBox on Android?

Tags: android, delphi, keyboard

In my Delphi Android app I need to prompt the user for a value and one of the many overloaded calls to InputQuery seems (just) ok for the task. Since the value is numeric, I'd like to offer only the numeric keyboard popup and ideally to restrict the entry characters to numbers alone, much like you can do with the FireMonkey TEdit control's FilterChars property.

It would appear that there is no actual TEdit available since InputQuery etc uses platform services to implement the Android code using java calls.

Is there a way of influencing the 'default' style of keyboard that will be popped up prior to my call to InputQuery?

(I have already seen that I can do this with a TEdit, the EMB samples and [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274897/how-can-i-show-the-keypad-type-vktnumberpad-with-decimal-for-input-with-delph) question ).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own class realizes Dialogs, or use ready example, [like that](http://fire-monkey.ru/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=1815).

Example looks like this:

```
procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  mY: TMyInputQuery;
begin
  mY := TMyInputQuery.Create(['Login:', 'Password:', 'aaaa', 'bbbb'],
    ['1', '2', '3', '4'], self, DialogEvent);
  mY.Edits[1].Password := true;

  mY.Edits[0].KillFocusByReturn := true;
  mY.Edits[0].ReturnKeyType := TReturnKeyType.Next;

  mY.Edits[1].KillFocusByReturn := true;
  mY.Edits[1].ReturnKeyType := TReturnKeyType.Next;

  mY.Edits[2].KillFocusByReturn := true;
  mY.Edits[2].ReturnKeyType := TReturnKeyType.Next;
  mY.Edits[2].KeyboardType := TVirtualKeyboardType.NumberPad;

  mY.Edits[3].KillFocusByReturn := true;
  mY.Edits[3].ReturnKeyType := TReturnKeyType.Next;
  mY.Edits[3].KeyboardType := TVirtualKeyboardType.PhonePad;
  mY.ShowMe;
end;
```